# Feture selection when the number features is too large for available memory

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am working with a data set with  about 200,000 features. Even though I can load the full data set using 54 GB of memory, my model crashes when it comes feature selection with LASSO. I prefer to find the best features out of all the ones, but given the insufficient memory, this doesn't seem to be an option.

As a solution, I thought of using manageable batches of features and find the features with highest Pearson correlation/mutual information with the target variable, or use model based feature selection on these batches of features.

But I feel that the above procedure will not provide me with the best features.

Is there another work around to reduce the feature space in this kind of a situation?

Comment: How many data samples do you have? One way would be to split the samples into batches and analyze all features for this subset. And do this with multiple randomly formed batches and do a voting in the end. I haven't tried this, but sounds reasonable.

Comment: I have about 8000 samples.

Comment: Then maybe you can split them into randomly selectd groups of 1000 each and do LASSO on each group. Then do it like 4-5 more time, each time with a different random grouping. In the end, see which feature was selected by LASSO the most number of times. This method will take more time, but relatively less memory.